# Matching wildcard without adding to the array with preg_match_all

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to capture the table text from an element that looks like this:

```
<span id="ctl00_MainContent_ListView2_ctrl2_ctl01_Label17" class="vehicledetailTable" style="display:inline-block;width:475px;">OWNED</span><br />
```

My *preg_match_all* looks like:

```
preg_match_all('~475px;">(.*?)</span><br />~', $ret, $vehicle);
```

The problem is there are other tables on the page that also match but have data not relevant to my query.  The data that I want are all in "**ListView2**," but the "**ct101_Label17**" varies - Label18, Label19, Label20, etc.

Since I'm not interested in capturing the label, is there a method to match the subject string without capturing the match? Something along the lines of:

```
<span id="ctl00_MainContent_ListView2_ctrl2_ctl01_[**WILDCARD HERE**]" class="vehicledetailTable" style="display:inline-block;width:475px;">OWNED</span><br />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be using `DOM` not regex

Comment: You might want to use some sort of html parsing library instead of regular expressions here. It's possible to solve this with regex, but you are in a danger zone here, where regex can cause some subtle edge case bugs, that are a nightmare to identify and debug.

Comment: I think your wildcard is [non](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)-quotes? `[^"]+` [see regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jH6cP8/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very poor solution that you are currently considering:

```
<span\b[^<>]*\bid="ctl00_MainContent_ListView2_ctrl2_ctl01_[^"]*"[^<>]*475px;">(.*?)</span><br\s*/>
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aU2dF5/1)

It makes sure we found a `<span>` tag and there is `id` attribute starting with `ctl00_MainContent_ListView2_ctrl2_ctl01_`, and there is some attribute (and you know it is `style`) ending with `475px;`, and then we just capture anything up to the closing `</span>` tag.

You can get this with DOM and XPath, which is a much safer solution that uses the same logic as above:

```
$html = "<span id=\"ctl00_MainContent_ListView2_ctrl2_ctl01_Label17\" class=\"vehicledetailTable\" style=\"display:inline-block;width:475px;\">OWNED</span><br />"; 
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$spans = $xpath->query("//span[starts-with(@id,'ctl00_MainContent_ListView2_ctrl2_ctl01_') and @class='vehicledetailTable'  and contains(@style,'475px;')]");
$data = array();
foreach ($spans as $span) {
    array_push($data, $span->textContent);
}
print_r($data);
```

Output: `[0] => OWNED`

Note that the XPath expression contains 3 conditions, feel free to modify any:

- `//span` - get all span tags that
- `starts-with(@id,'ctl00_MainContent_ListView2_ctrl2_ctl01_')` - have an attribute `id` with value starting with `ctl00_MainContent_ListView2_ctrl2_ctl01_`
- `@class='vehicledetailTable'` - and have `class` attribute with value equal to `vehicledetailTable`
- `contains(@style,'475px;')` - and have a `style` attribute whose value contains `475px;`.

Conditions are enclosed into `[...]` and are joined with `or` or `and`. They can also be grouped with round brackets. You can also use `not(...)` to invert the condition. XPath is very helpful in such situations.

Comment: This works brilliantly and is a much nicer solution than the way I was doing it.  THANK YOU!